# BNF and EBNF Syntax for while loops in C#

Tags: formal-grammars, c

Given the programming language C#, how would I be able to write the BNF and EBNF grammar syntax of its while loop?

After trying to search and understand more, I got this as my BNF grammar for while loops

< while-statement > :: = < do-statement >< while-statement >
| < do-statement >

though I don't think it's quite right

Comment: Have you tried checking [the specification of the `while` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1292-the-while-statement) or the [grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/grammar#a3-syntactic-grammar)?

Answer (score 1):

The common element in "while statements" and "do statements" is the continuation condition, which is an expression inside parentheses, always indicated with the keyword `while`. If you wanted to, you could capture this commonality with something like:

```
<while-clause> ::= "while" "(" <expression> ")"
<while-statement> ::= <while-clause> <embedded-statement>
<do-statement> ::= "do" <embedded-statement> <while-clause> ";"
```

I'm not sure whether that adds any readability to the grammar. The actual [C# grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/grammar#a3-syntactic-grammar) doesn't bother; it just uses

```
<while-statement> ::= "while" "(" <expression> ")" <embedded-statement>
<do-statement> ::= "do" <embedded-statement> "while" "(" <expression> ")" ";"
```

Thanks to [@JörgWMittag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154468/bnf-and-ebnf-syntax-for-while-loops-in-c#comment324800_154468) for the above link, in which you have to search for `while_statement` because the productions aren't tagged. Also see [the specification text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#129-iteration-statements).

Either way, the productions simply reflect the evident syntax. At a high level, you can get surprisingly far into the writing of a grammar by just explaining the construct in your own language. ("A *while statement* starts with the keyword `while`, followed by the continuation expression surrounded by parentheses, and then the statement to be iterated.")

The only subtlety here is the use of `<embedded-statement>` instead of, say, `<statement>`. That's because C#, like C and other C-derivatives, doesn't permit embedded statements to be declarations or to have labels. (If you want to do that, you'd need to embed a "block" (that is, a list of statements inside `{`…`}`).